# how to calculate speed using samples in c#

Tags: c#, performance, statistics

Each x seconds I grab a sample of the current time and speed

```
(time / number of objects created) = avg speed
```

I want to write a class that understands how to use the samples to calculate better average speeds.

At first I thought of speed as double[] , and then average out using Linq, but because timers and threads are not deterministic, I might have samples taken at

- 4 sec
- 4.2 sec
- 5.1 sec
- 5 sec
- 5 sec
- 4.101 sec

etc..

I considered TimeSpan as the marker, but that just shows deltas between rows.
so I was thinking of maybe a Tuple or KeyValue, but it is not so simple to calculate the average speeds using TimeSpan

Does anyone have an idea ?

thanks

Comment: the whole point is to take time measurements not object measurements. i want to know how moany objects i have created every 5 sec lets say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of Timer/Stopwatch to control the real time:

```
StopWatch watch;
Timer tmr;

List<double> samples;

void initSampling()
{

    samples = new List<double>();
    watch = new Stopwatch();
    tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
    tmr.Interval = 1000;
    tmr.Start();
    watch.Start();
}

void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double items = ...;//store the number of items created
    watch.Stop();

    double itemsPerSec = items / watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    double timePerItem = 1.0 / itemsPerSec;

    samples.Add(timePerItem);

    watch.Restart();
}
```

Comment: interesting, but I am looking for the opposite. I want to know how long it takes to create an object, not how many objects in a tick.

Comment: get the inverse of itemsPerSec and you have the length to construct one item... changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

At every 'tick' store the current time.
From the number of items since the last tick and the timestamp of the last tick you can calculate items per second for the latest interval. Store this value in a list, along with length of interval (for example in milliseconds).

Your overall average is (exactly) the weighted average of this list.
(weights are the milliseconds)

Comment: my items run for a few hours, under your current answer I will finish my memory only on the stats table.

Comment: Sorry, but sounds like a misunderstanding. Could you provide an example: How many objects after 4.9s, how many after the next 5.1s and so on? I'll explain what I mean using with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a PerformanceCounter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx? You just count the number of objects created, and the performance counter automatically calculates the average "speed" (I think you mean the rate at which objects are created, or objects per second).